# Change the default color of links in Keynote 8.3 macOS Template

Tags: macos, keynote

I have a keynote template and the links come up in a teal blue color. However, the default on some templates is black, so I know that this can be changed. How do I change it?

Comment: iOS - macOS ? Which version of Keynote?  In the macOS version you can make a custom template with all kinds of default styling.  If you are asking about changing the default on EVERY template, you would have to create new ones with your tweaks.  Please update your question with a little more detail if possible.  Cheers!

Comment: @bjbk, it's not clear how to specify the link color on the custom template; can you tell me how to do that?